# Связка Django Rest framework и Channels

Tags: python, django, rest, websocket, channels

Я разрабатываю бэкенд для мобильного приложения.
Я использую Django Rest framework, и сейчас мне необходимо поставить веб-сокеты.
Для этой цели я выбрал Channels. Я понял как связать Django и Channels. Но я не пойму как связать Rest framework с Channels. Благодарю заранее каждого кто хоть чем то поможет…